# Can a sealed Scala class be externally "extended" by setting/restricting parameters?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I'm considering using [Scalactic](http://www.scalactic.org/)'s "[Or](http://www.artima.com/docs-scalatest-2.2.0-RC1/index.html#org.scalactic.Or)", which is defined as:

```
sealed abstract class Or[+G,+B] ...
```

but I'd like to declare a subclass that sets **B**, as in:

```
class MyOr[G] extends Or[G,MyBadness] {}
```

that would be used ubiquitously in my project.  Note that this class has no body; it's only purpose is to set the type parameter.

Is there any way to do this other than the usual implicit conversion/wrapper hack?

Answer (score 7):

One option, avoiding any inheritance at all, would be to define a type synonym at package level:

```
sealed abstract class Or[+G,+B]
class MyBadness

package object the_project_name {
  type MyOr[G] = Or[G, MyBadness]

  class ActualOr extends MyOr[Int] {
    val bla = ()
  }
}
```

Comment: Beware that this is subject to a highlighting bug in IntelliJ: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7891. It works in compiler/interpreter, though.

Comment: This doesn't work, AFAICT.  In your example it works, because "Or" is defined in the same file.  But in the real case, where "Or" is defined externally, it gets compile error `illegal inheritance from sealed class Or`, as one would expect.  I'm mystified by all the up-votes, though - maybe I'm missing something!

Comment: Oh, right. Seems like I (and everyone else) overlooked the `sealed`. But if it's sealed in the library you're using, you can't extend it anyway, can you? The type synonyme alone should work, I think...

Comment: Yes, you can't literally extend it; I was hoping to find some way to "alias" the subclass as with "type", but with better scoping rules.  I could, probably, put the type in a package object in every using package, but... yuck!  I'm just going to implicit-convert it for now, and fork the Scalactic impl if/when necessary - optimize when no longer premature.